# CMake in Visual Studio does not set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR correctly

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a CMake project which I am building in Visual Studio. In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have this statement:

```
if(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Prevented in-tree build. ")
endif()
```

In my CMakeSettings.json I have this line:

```
{
"configurations":[
 {
 "name": "x64-Debug",
 //...
 "buildRoot": "{projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
}
//...
]
//....
}
```

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=vs-2019) `buildRoot` maps to `-DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.

I get the error that you can see in the above if statement.

If I print the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable, it looks nothing like `buildRoot`, it's just the root of the project.

It did work previously, but I used CMake in the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 to try to build the project, but now, if I try to build again from Visual Studio, I get the above error (in-tree build).

Any idea what's wrong and how to properly set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` in CMakeSettings.json?

Comment: Your syntax in json is problematic and not being expanded. Please try:

    `"buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",`

Note the missing `$`

Comment: You are missing a `$` in `{projectDir}`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo in my question. In my actual code, buildRoot is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by deleting the CMakeCache.txt file. Turns out, I called CMake from the same directory as the project, and it created a CMakeCache.txt file containing the bad build directory.